# showing ends of previous and next bootstrap carousel images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Ive seen the other post about this subject and have played around with the css but can't seem to get this one problem away.

Im building a carousel with bootstrap and would like the next and previous images to show their ends and have a smooth transition. Currently the "next" image on the right is not showing up and the transition is very "glitchy". any ideas on how i can get the displayed image in the center with the next and previous images showing their ends?

[Image shows carousel not showing the next image and the current image not centered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqGw9.jpg)

```css
/* === CAROUSEL === */

.carousel-inner {
    height: 515px;
}

.item {
    height: 515px;
}

.carousel-inner .item img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 515px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
    width: 150%;
    left: -25%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-control.left, 
.carousel-control.right {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 2%;
}
```

```html
 <!-- CAROUSEL SECTION
        =================================================================== -->
        
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="assets/img/carousel-1.jpg" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="assets/img/carousel-2.jpg" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="assets/img/carousel-3.jpg" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
            ...
          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Carousel JS -->
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 10000
            })
            $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
                var next = $(this).next();
                if (!next.length) {
                    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                }
                next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                if (next.next().length > 0) {
                    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out this pen: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/RKavve